# find orphaned methods in codebase

Tags: .net, visual-studio, refactoring

I'm sure we've all seen it before...A code base that has been around for a year or two, and as features have been added and bugs fixed, we end up with pieces of code that aren't actually in use anymore.  I'm wondering if there is a way (especially in VS.NET with or without a third-party tool) to search the codebase and show me which methods are NEVER used anywhere else in the code?

The one challenge I can think of in regards to this type of utility would be the inability to map back when implicit type conversions are occuring.  But assuming that wasn't a problem, what are my options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) will warn you of methods where nothing calls them.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, one of the things that [FxCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/) does is identify unused bits of code, but it sometimes misses stuff. However, your best bet would likely be [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Answer (score 2):

Remember though that any public-facing method, property, or field can be accessed via reflection or in a derived type in a seperate assembly.

FxCop is the right answer here, but you also need to limit accessibility to your code. I.e. decorate things with private/protected/internal where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The following tool can find orphan/unused code:

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx)